# Python groupby by using lambda

Tags: lambda, group-by

I am trying to group some people by lambda function
(this is a bank-additional-full dataset)

here is what I am trying to do

df['job_group'] = df['job'].apply(
lambda x :
'Jobless' if x == 'retired' else 'Currently Working'

)

So, I am trying to group by
Jobless : unemployed, retired, student
Currently Working : admin, services, technician ..etc

but if I try like this

df['job_group'] = df['job'].apply(
lambda x :
'Jobless' if x == 'retired','student','umemployed' else 'Currently Working'

it does not work

I know this might look silly, but I know almost nothing about it. I would greatly appreciate if you can save my life for now...!!

)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with List comprehension.

```
df['job_status'] = ['Jobless' if x in ['retired','student','unemployed'] else 'Currently working' for x in df['job']]
```